# What are the differences between hierarchical, network and relational data models?

Tags: rdbms, hierarchical, datamodel

Please tell me what is difference between hierarchical, network and relational data models?

Comment: This is too broad but nevertheless also a faq--both reasons for being off-topic. Please see [ask] & other [help] links.

Comment: @ philipxy here i want to know the differences between hierarchical, network and relational data models.if you please tell me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hierarchical model**

```
1.One to many or one to one relationships.
2.Based on parent child relationship.
3.Retrieve algorithms are complex and asymmetric
4.Data Redundancy more
```

**Network model**

```
1.Many to many relationships.
2.Many parents as well as many children.
3.Retrieve algorithms are complex and symmetric
4.Data Redundancy more
```

**Relational model**

```
1.One to One,One to many, Many to many relationships.
2.Based on relational data structures.
3.Retrieve algorithms are simple and symmetric
4.Data Redundancy less
```